# React & Firebase: How to update the count of a specific document in collection in real time?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Issue: How do I go about incrementing a user's number of points in their own document on each click and the result presented live in real time?

I understand real time uses a snapshot listener, but I can't seem to get it working quickly.

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const userId = e.target.id

    db.collection('users').doc(userId)
  .update({
    housePoints: db.FieldValue.increment(1)
  });
```

Below is the full code of the component to give an overall view of the issue I am having.

```
import './ClassStats.scss';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Sidebar from '../../components/sidebar/Sidebar';
import Navbar from '../../components/navbar/Navbar';
import StudentView from '../../components/StudentView/StudentView';
import {
  collection,
  doc,
  onSnapshot,
  updateDoc,
  serverTimestamp,
  setDoc,
} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../../firebase';

const ClassStats = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //LISTEN IN REAL TIME
    const unsub = onSnapshot(
      collection(db, 'users'),
      (snapshot) => {
        let list = [];
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          list.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
        });
        console.log(list);
        setData(list);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
    return () => {
      unsub();
    };
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const userId = e.target.id
    db.collection('users').doc(userId)
  .update({
    housePoints: db.FieldValue.increment(1)
  });
    
    }
  return (
    <div className="classStats">
      <Navbar />
      <div className="classStatsContainer">
        <Sidebar />
        <div className="test">
          <ul className="students">
            {data.map((item) => (
              <StudentView key={item.id} {...item} onClick={handleClick} />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ClassStats;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I hope this is the best and most efficient method.

```
const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const userId = e.target.id
    const docRef = doc(db,'users', userId);

    await updateDoc(docRef, {
      housePoints: increment(1)
  });
  }
```